# Can rpm spec files be used to support SIMD-aware packaged builds?

Tags: rpm

http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/ch-rpm-multi.html makes clear that RPM can be used to target different platforms, but is it possible to use RPM to target multiple different flavours within a platform?

Motivation: Something compiled to run on x86-64 using AVX extensions can't be run on earlier x86-64 hardware. The package name could specify that the necessary compiler flags were used, and one could rely on the user to install the best one for the hardware, but it would be better to be able to defer such a problem to the package manager. Otherwise, one is forced to use only the least-common-denominator SSE2 SIMD support, and waste a lot of the user's hardware.

Answer (score 0):

You can create RPM package with software compiled with some extension enabled. That is no problem. However you cannot use /usr/bin/rpm to handle the restriction and to choose best package for the platform.

But user can do that.

You can create the packages:

```
Name: foo-general
Provides: foo
```

and then some other:

```
Name: foo-recent-amd-only
Provides: foo

Name: foo-recent-intel-only
Provides: foo
```

Each of those packages can be build with different compiler flags. They can even be build from one source package.

So if some other software requires (or user install) "foo", he can choose to install either foo-general, foo-recent-amd-only or foo-recent-intel-only